# could not run react-native application due to Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

i have tried alot of solutions. may be zip downloading interrupted or not completed successfully. but i make a new project by clone my repo and that gives me same error . i also tried by delete gradle directory from main folder of my project. and there is not dist folder or zip file inside the gradle directory. here is the complete log of error

```
Unzipping /var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.1- 
all/bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew/gradle-4.1-all.zip to 
/var/root/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.1all/bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening 
zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:159)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$500(Install.java:26)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:69)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:46)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access
(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:46)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:126)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
 Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for 
 details.
 Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected 
 and have
 set up your Android development environment:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Cd android

./gradlew clean

Cd ..

Sudo React-native run-android

Comment: did you use sudo?

Comment: yeah i did that

Comment: when i do with sudo it give me same error zip file error